# Dealing with now archived modules i.e. configuration, express, socketio, errors

Tags: feathersjs

I have a fjs 3.0 project that I just coming back to after a few months.   In the meantime it seems several modules have been archived and "moved into the main feathersjs module".   So I'm a bit confused. How do I clean up my package.json and app.js to reflect this?  I deleted /errors, /configuration, /socketio and /express from my package.json now what has to change in app.js as without these I get missing module errors?  I generated a new app with 3.8.0 cli just to see what was in app.js and it's the same.  So I am confused about this whole "archive" situation.

```
const express = require('@feathersjs/express')
const configuration = require('@feathersjs/configuration')
const rest = require('@feathersjs/express/rest')
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a purely organizational change and does not affect how you use Feathers in any way.

Many other projects like Babel, React and Meteor are already using this "Monorepo" style of managing multiple packages. You can find the issue related to this at [feathersjs/feathers#462](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/462)

Comment: If I understand you now keep/maintain all these modules in one repo (what? feathers?) and when you have changes to publish you clone that module to their corresponding readonly repo and then publish to npm from there?  In other words those readonly repos will show new releases but only via the mono repo?  If that is the case I understand why it doesn't affect me.

Comment: The archived repositories will no longer be updated. All code changes will now be made in the main Feathers repository at https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers. Each individual module release will however continue to be published to npm under the names you are already using. If you are using the versions published on npm or yarn, nothing will change. Only those published versions should be used. Installing from Git or GitHub references is not recommended (but will continue to work for old versions).

Comment: Ok, then only thing confusing is that the homepage/repository links on the npm page https://www.npmjs.com/package/@feathersjs/configuration takes you to the old archive instead of to the new location.  https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/tree/master/packages/configuration.  https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/blob/master/packages/configuration/package.json

Comment: Totally. Just wrapping up the last updates to make releases with the updated links, you caught it right in the middle :D